# Custom button or link with visualforce page in managed package in lightning org

Tags: visualforce, managed-package, custom-button, lightning

It is one of the things, which make me crazy in salesforce. You create a custom button, which opens a page. It works fine in your org, but it fails in managed package org, in addition it should be adjusted for lightning environment... 
And you cant test it until deploy it to managed package org and there you cant fix the issue >:-]

Any way, could you please provide a simple solution to create button, which will be on standard lightning layout and which opens a visualforce page in managed package org. I thought to do something like this:

```
window.open('{!URLFOR($Page.SomePage,'',[id=someValue])}
```

But it won't work, as $Page is not work in custom buttons\links or i dont know how to use it.

Then i thought to get somehow namespace with using soap call from javascript:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/36.0/connection.js")}
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/36.0/apex.js")}

var nameSpace = sforce.apex.execute("orgNamespace.Util", "getNamespace", {});
```

but again, we have to know namespace in order to reach the class...[facepalm]

Will be grateful for any solutions!

Comment: I found a solution here:
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28974/determining-namespace-prefix-in-javascript-and-apex