# Managed package API URL is different then unmanaged package?

Tags: apex, managed-package, security-review

After my app is granted an OAuth token by the user, I take the "url" provided in the OAuth request, and the token, and make a request back to salesforce to store some settings.

In my unmanaged package testing the url looked something like this:

https://na3.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/customrestendpoint

And this domain matched the domain in salesforce while the user was using the app.

Now that I uploaded a *Managed package though, it seems to be different. The URL in Salesforce looks like this

https://appnamespace.na3.salesforce.com/apex/blahblah

and the POST request to https://na3.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/customrestendpoint is returning a 404

Is this expected? Do I need to append the app namespace to my API requests to the custom REST endpoint? Or is the namespace optional and can I just omit it when creating the managed package?

Answer (score 6):

In the org you are developing the managed package in that namespace is implied when no namespace is specified. In the case of customer orgs this is not true - they have their own namespace for unmanaged components, and your namespace needs to be explicitly included on apexrest requests.

[The docs do describe this, but it's a bit down the page and easy to miss if you aren't looking for it.](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_methods.htm)

> Apex REST methods can be used in managed and unmanaged packages. When calling Apex REST methods that are contained in a managed package, you need to include the managed package namespace in the REST call URL. For example, if the class is contained in a managed package namespace called packageNamespace and the Apex REST methods use a URL mapping of /MyMethod/*, the URL used via REST to call these methods would be of the form https://instance.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/packageNamespace/MyMethod/

This is substantially easier than trying to prepend the subdomain, since the format for that can vary wildly based on if my domain is enabled, if you're in a sandbox, and other factors.

In the event it's helpful to do so, you can determine your code's current namespace at runtime. See https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/28977/60

Comment: Interesting. So if my external app is running the same code on the OAuth Callback in staging/development as it is in production, how am I supposed to know if I need to append the prefix or not?

Comment: @user1813867 You can query the Organization object for NamespacePrefix. It'll be null for subscribers and not-null for your developer org where the package lives.

Comment: Interesting. I'll try that. Hope it works!

Comment: Be aware that only users with view all data or apex running without sharing will be able to query the Organization table, which is one of the reasons I prefer the answer I linked at the end of mine - you won't have to justify it in security review and it doesn't burn a query.

Comment: I wonder if I could query for the namespace in the apex code that kicks off the OAuth flow, then pass that namespace in the state parameter to my webapp. That way I could record both the url, bearer token, and namespace in the initial setup call.

Comment: Extra note: the namespace is case sensitive (as URLs should be), for in my scenario I had to use CAPS for the namespace part of the URL or I got a miss.