# Using wildcards for column names in dynamic soql in apex

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql

I have a scenario where my columns names can be of form `genesis__prod__c`/`docgen__prod__c`/`lnd__prod__c`,etc depending upon which package is using my solution package. Here `genesis`, `docgen` and `lnd` are different product packages using my solution.

My solution needs to fetch any of these fields (`genesis__prod__c`/`docgen__prod__c`/`lnd__prod__c`) from their respective `sObjects` in their products.

I want to construct a generic query which will omit the namespace using a wildcard and only look for `prod__c` in specified `sObject`. With such a solution, I wouldn't have to hardcode any namespace in my query.

For example, I don't want to form my query like this

```
String query = 'select Id,Name,docgen__CL_Product__c from '+ sObjectType + ' where id= \'' + appId + '\'';
List<sObject> runtimeDeterminedObject = Database.query(query+' LIMIT 1');
```

Here I have specifically mentioned `docgen__CL_Product__c` name to be fetched from a runtime resolved sObject name `sObjectType` wrt an `appId`

How can I form a query where I do not have to provide namespace `docgen,genesis` before `prod__c`. I do not want to write `if-else` for each product which can utilize my package.

Answer (score 3):

Nope. You can't do it. Every field in your `SELECT` clause must be one, specific field. You have to loop through the object's field map and pull in the fields individually.

```
List<String> prodFields = new List<String>();
for (String field : sObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet())
    if (field.contains('__prod__c'))
        prodFields.add(field);
```

Comment: Thanks. I did the same after searching for a while. I'm looping through the sObject and checking each reference field which is equal to the lookup sObject of *__prod__c and taking that particular apiName given that apiName contains __prod__c similar to your suggestion apiName.contains('__prod__c').

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure in context of managed package, but if you can get the namespace then you can construct your query based on the namespace of the org.

Update:

**This approach will work if you are installing a class through your package.**

Assume the class name is 'namespace', you can get the raw namespace by using:

```
nameSpacePrefix =namespace.class.getName().substringBefore('namespace').substringBefore('.');
```

Look at mattandneil's answer for other ways to get the namespace prefix:

[Namespace Prefix in JavaScript and Apex within Installed Package](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28974/determining-namespace-prefix-in-javascript-and-apex)

```
public class namespace {

    public static string nameSpacePrefix;
    public static String query;
        public namespace(){
         nameSpacePrefix= '';
        }
        
        public static string constructmysoqlquery(){
           nameSpacePrefix= [SELECT NamespacePrefix FROM Organization].NamespacePrefix;
           // could be handled better by adding the namespaces in a custom setting.
           
            set<string> namespaceset = new  set<string>{'genesis','docgen','lnd'};
               if(namespaceset.contains(nameSpacePrefix)){
                   query = 'select Id,Name,'+nameSpacePrefix+'_Product__c from '+ sObjectType + ' where id= \'' + appId + '\'';;
               }
        return query;
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: If this is in someone else's org the namespace will be null, no?

Comment: @Adrian Larson thats the point i was not able to research, this might be open ended unless tested https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000092MmIAI

Comment: `SELECT NamespacePrefix FROM Organization` will bring namespace of the particular package but what if multiple manage packages are installed in the same org.

Comment: @Cyclotron3x3 I belive then you may have to go for approach where you will have to look for the class installed through your package, I am not an expert with packages but this post seem to tackle your question : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28974/determining-namespace-prefix-in-javascript-and-apex